# "Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=")" Terraform error when trying to create a map and convert it into JSON

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm using Terraform to create a certificate in HashiCorp Vault, GCP Service Account and Service Account Key.

I'd like to use the attribute values from the above resources to create a GCP service account credential template for later use. I'm trying to achieve it by declaring a local and encoding it's content using the `jsonencode` function:

```
locals {
  client_email_content                     = "${google_service_account.myaccount.account_id}@${var.gcp_project_id}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  service_account_credential_template      = {
    jsonencode(
      { 
        type = "service_account"
        project_id = "${var.gcp_project_id}"
        private_key_id = "${split("/", google_service_account_key.mykey.id)[5]}"
        private_key = "${vault_pki_secret_backend_cert.vault_gcp_cert.private_key}"
        client_email = "${local.client_email_content}"
        client_id = "${google_service_account.myaccount.unique_id}"
        auth_uri = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
        token_uri = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
        auth_provider_x509_cert_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
        client_x509_cert_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/${urlencode(local.client_email_content)}"
      }
    )
  }
}
```

When trying trying to apply the above code to my Terraform configuration i get the following error:

> Expected an attribute value, introduced by an equals sign ("=")

I've tried to put the map keys of k/v pairs into quotation marks and remove the semicolon pair after `jsonencode`, but this error message keeps reappearing. There are no empty values, since all of these resources get created properly and export attribute values.

What could be the source of this error?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the opening and closing curly brackets around `jsonencode`. This should work:

```
  service_account_credential_template = jsonencode(
    {
      type                         = "service_account"
      project_id                   = var.gcp_project_id
      private_key_id               = split("/", google_service_account_key.mykey.id)[5]
      private_key                  = vault_pki_secret_backend_cert.vault_gcp_cert.private_key
      client_email                 = local.client_email_content
      client_id                    = google_service_account.myaccount.unique_id
      auth_uri                     = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"
      token_uri                    = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url  = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
      client_x509_cert_url         = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/${urlencode(local.client_email_content)}"
    }
  )
```